# Release mode diagnostics in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Is there any way to get React Native to output all `console.log` calls to same place `NSLog` goes?

Is there a way I can see the outputs from `console.log` in Release mode?

If not is there an NSLog helper for react native I can use?

(note I know that in Debug mode I have a multitude of ways of getting this info, but I am having specific issue with Release mode that I need to diagnose.)

Answer (score 57):

In `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
```

Then in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
RCTSetLogThreshold(RCTLogLevelInfo - 1);
```

This sets the react logger to log all levels to NSLog as opposed to the release default which is: `RCTLogLevelError` which is `console.error` I guess :)

This allows you to have a totally honest "release" mode build with all the verbose logging you want.

Comment: For my RN project 'RCTLog.h' didn't work but #import <React/RCTLog.h> did.  Thanks for this!

Comment: I added this code inside app delegate.m and archived to create a build. Please note: I am a react native developer , I do not know much about Xcode. Where can I see the release build logs now after adding this code

Comment: I have the same question as @AnkushRishi Where is the actual log?

Comment: Yet another "how/where can I see this log"?

Comment: Cool!  Now do android :D

Comment: You can see these logs on xcode (debug area) its the bottom windows, where you can change to (all outputs, debugger outputs, target outputs)

Comment: React Native 0.71 this does not work, `RCTSetLogThreshold` not found

Answer (score 0):

after add `RCTSetLogThreshold(RCTLogLevelInfo - 1);` to your AppDelegate.m
you can connect your iPhone and view logs in Mac console.app.