# React Native production app remote diagnostics / user assistance

Tags: reactjs, logging, react-native, production, diagnostics

I have published an app built with React Native.  Currently it's iOS only, but eventually may be released for Android as well.  I'd like a cross-platform solution to remotely assist customers that run into bugs, crashes or any unexpected behavior.  While the app could continuously log everything to a server, I've found that that's not very helpful since customers usually have very specific points in time that they need help with.  Sifting through continuous logs is time consuming and generally a waste of resources.

My hope is to give the user the ability to press a button to send the stack trace, the last N minutes worth of logs, etc directly to me.  This wouldn't work in the case of a hard crash of course.  The vast majority of the time the app is functional when there's something they need help with.

A pie-in-the-sky idea would be to let the user share their screen with me.

Found this related question but it doesn't fully encompass what I'm trying to accomplish:

[Release mode diagnostics in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089772/release-mode-diagnostics-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

BugSnag looks promising. It's a paid service.

https://www.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native-error-reporting

Answer (score 0):

I tried BugSnag and a few other services.  In the end, Sentry has the most reliable and simplest RN library.  It's also free for the Developer plan (5k errors per month is plenty enough for us, and supports multiple apps).
https://sentry.io/pricing/